# Setup Dynamic Axis in Vico

Tags: android, kotlin, charts

I am using charting library [Vico](https://github.com/patrykandpatrick/vico) with version [2.0.0-alpha.8](https://patrykandpatrick.com/vico/wiki/2.0.0-alpha.8/) to draw line charts. My chart will dynamically update data when users pressing buttons. However, I found that the bottom axis won't be updated.

The x labels in my bottom axis should be changed after data changing. The size of my data will dynamically change. And my axis value formatter is like

```
AxisValueFormatter<AxisPosition.Horizontal.Bottom> { i, _, _ ->
    data[i.toInt()].x
}
```

When the source data changes, but the bottom axis is not updated. I will get the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the size of the new data is smaller than the old data.

I also tried to use `remember` or state in `ViewModel` for axis value formatter, but bottom axis isn't updated after formatter changes.

Thank you in advance if anyone have any suggestions for this question.